# Formatting Mysql returned Array for JSON

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

I am doing a mysql query that pulls relative data from 3 tables based on an ID provided. **My problem comes when I try to format the sql query so that when I turn the resulting array into a JSON object the data is nested correctly.**

**My SQL Query as of now:**

```
  select * from Players join SchoolData on Players.School = SchoolData.ID join LocationData on SchoolData.Location = LocationData.ID where Players.ID =%d
```

**When I JSONify the results of the above query I get:**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "City": "San Diego",
      "Height": 77,
      "ID": 7,
      "Location": 7,
      "Mascot": "Aztecs",
      "Name": "San Diego State Aztecs",
      "School": 11,
      "State": "CA",
      "Weight": 196
    }
  ]
}
```

**I am trying to get my results to look like the following example which nest the data that is pulled from other tables.**

```
 {
    “data”:[
        {
            “student”:
                {
                “id”:xxx-xxx-xxx, 
                “name”: “name1”, 
                “school”: 
                    {
                        “id”:xxxx, 
                        “address”:
                            {
                                “id”:xxx, 
                                “city”: “mycity”, 
                                “state”: “OH”
                            }, 

                        “name”: “myschool”, 
                        “mascot”: “wildcats”
                    }, 
                “height”: 72, 
                “weight”: 180
        },
    ]
}
```

I have been looking at the `FOR JSON`  command (that is used in SQL) and instead of selecting `*` all I can use the `AS` command in my query which should help with my label before the value returned but not the nesting of data.

**I am just not sure if this is done pre query or post.**

**UPDATE
I am finding the following mysql functions:** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html  but I am not sure if this is what I am looking for.

Comment: Something is here but i dont think u looking for this:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-shell-json-output.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
 std.id, std.name, sch.id, add.id, add.city, add.state, sch.name, sch.mascot, std.height, std.weight 
FROM
student std LEFT JOIN school sch ON < join condition >
LEFT JOIN address ON < join condition >
FOR JSON AUTO
```

Try something like this, FOR JSON AUTO should convert it into JSON string that you want.

Comment: Thanks the FOR JSON is a SQL syntax though.